# What is the fish equivalent of set -e?

Tags: scripts, fish

bash has a [builtin called set](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) with an "exit early" feature described as follows:

> -e
>
> Exit immediately if a pipeline (see Pipelines), which may consist of a single simple command (see Simple Commands), a list (see Lists), or a compound command (see Compound Commands) returns a non-zero status.

If you write a bash script that begins with `set -e` it will abort at the first failing command, rather than continuing to run all subsequent commands (the default behavior).

You could achieve a similar effect in fish by chaining commands with `and` but that would get unwieldy pretty quickly. (`sudo apt update; and sudo apt upgrade` is one thing, but imagine a substantial script)

Is there an equivalent setting in fish to exit a script on the first non-zero exit status?

**Notes:**

- [Fish for bash users](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/fish_for_bash_users.html) doesn't mention this.
- [set](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/set.html) is a very different command in fish

Comment: There's an issue in the fish-shell github repo discussing this very feature: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/510 -- the issue has been open for almost 10 years, so don't expect a quick resolution.

Comment: @glennjackman It's a "negative answer", but it's still the right answer.  Would you consider copying the comment over to an answer so that it can be accepted and closed-out?

Comment: thanks @glennjackman, I've answered the question based on your feeback

Comment: thanks @FabianBoehm too, your answer would have been perfect with a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately fish does not have this feature. There is a long-standing issue ([fish-shell#510](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/510), open since 2013) discussing if and how it could be implemented in fish.